# How to access different realtime databses in my firebase project?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `firebase realtime DB`. In it I have selected the 3 dot on the right and created a second DB, **Its name is: "project-SomeNumberString"**

**In my app how can I now access that database instead of the original (which just lacks the string of numbers)?**

Comment: @twothreezarsix could you expand on that?

Comment: @twothreezarsix yes your assumption is correct. The second half however I do not unerstand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is described in the [documentation on sharding](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding).  You will specifically want to use the sample code in the section "[Connect your app to multiple database instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#connect_your_app_to_multiple_database_instances)":

> Use the database reference to access data stored in secondary database
> instances. You can get the reference for a specific database instance
> by URL or app. If you don't specify a URL, you'll get the reference
> for the app's default database instance.
>
> ```
> // Get the default database instance for an app
>
> var ref: DatabaseReference!
>
> ref = Database.database().reference()
>
>
> // Get a secondary database instance by URL
> var ref: DatabaseReference!
>
> ref = Database.database("https://testapp-1234.firebaseio.com").reference()
> ```

You will need to use this secondary instance to make your queries.